# Emigrating to Netherlands from ZA, how to get proof of residence in ZA?

Tags: netherlands, south-africa, south-african-citizens

In the next few weeks I will be moving to Amsterdam to work for an indefinite amount of time. To apply for the 30% ruling in the Netherlands I need some sort of government form that says I have been a South African resident for the last 24 months. Where would I get such a form and what would it be called?

I have be to my local Home Affairs office and was told they could give me a `Declaration of Citizenship` but I have been told that this is not the correct form. So what would the correct form be?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: For future South Africans needing this information, if you have been working for two or more years go to SARS and ask for your tax number, a form will be given to you with your registration date, address and tax number. This is a valid proof of residence for Netherlands 30% Ruling :)

Comment: Thanks Dean for the edit, just the info I was looking for!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below are examples of what can be accepted as a proof of residence:

***Recent Utility Bill (i.e. telephone, gas, electric) (Please note that a mobile phone bill will not be accepted as a valid Proof of Residence).*** ***Recent Bank Statement, Recent Mortgage Statement, Signed Lease Agreement still within term Bank, Investment Letter, Rental checks, Credit card, Pay check stub Rent payment, voter registration card.***

A utility bill shows you get service at that address under your name, it's usually accepted, but not always - it has to be accompanied by a photo id with the same address to get your credit report.

**EDIT**:

[***THIS LINK***](http://www.gab.wi.gov/sites/default/files/publication/154/proof_of_residence_pdf_29621.pdf) is an example of how you can prove your residence through Voter registration card!

Comment: Thank you, I see you mentioned "voter registration card." I think this will be the easiest either that or a bank statement.

Comment: I edited the answer, so if you decide to proof your residence through Voter's registration card you can refer to that link.. Good luck!